# How to run my tests from inside setup.py (setuptools)?

Tags: python, unit-testing, setuptools

I know the setuptools has an option to run your tests but I didn't find any information regarding how to make it run my tests.

By default my tests are included with the module and I use discovery to detect and run them-all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `test` command option to `setup.py` ([documented here](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#test)) as extended by `setuptools` (or `Distribute`).

Comment: As you can imagine this is what I tried, but I was not able to figure it out from the doc, on how to make it run the tests effectively. While enable it run nothing.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose better with so little information.  Please update your question to include the contents of your `setup.py` file, your directory layout, and the results you expect and that you see.